# Java applet not launching using JNLP when both 32bit and 64bit java version is installed?

Tags: java, jvm, 32bit-64bit, jnlp, japplet

i am trying to launch a java applet using a jnlp file. The java application can run only using 64bit java. In the JNLP file i have made

```
<resources arch="amd64">
```

So that the applet will use java 64bit JVM.

But the issue is if the versions of both 32bit and 64bit installed in the machine is same then the applet is not launching.

If 64bit java version is higher than 32bit version, then app is launch.

I want to make the app launch when both versions are same also.

Can anyone help?

---

UPDATE 1:

Somtimes, i get only the below exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\tmp_cache4924041859582810166.tmp (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web). The 'plugin' powers both applets and JWS.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Andrew, i am using only Java 8, still am facing this issue,.. any other workaround? thanks in advance..

Comment: *"i am using only Java 8"* How is that relevant to deployment (on **other** people's machines)? *"any other workaround?"* The SDK 9(+) contains a tool which is supposed to be able to make standalone executables (they work with no JRE installed) I think it's called `jlink`, but have not looked into it much.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Hi, I have attached the stack trace, can you find anything that can be useful?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I cant use SDK 9+, our product guideline is to use only Java 8..

Comment: AFAIU The jlink tool makes the JRE on the client machine irrelevant. But I don't have enough experience to support it, nor the motivation to try helping support Java 8.